# Coding multiple linear regression in R when sample size is smaller than variable size

Tags: r, multiple-regression, overfitting, linear-algebra, glmnet

Here is my multiple linear regression code where $Xtrain$ and $Xtest$ are matrices containing respectively the train and test samples in rows and explanatory variables in columns, and $ytrain$ and $ytest$ are the output column vectors containing the response variable values respectively for the train and test samples.

`ginv()` is the generalized inverse function since normal inverse (function `solve()`) would not work here since the number of variables (1000) is larger than the number of samples (30).

$pred$ is the prediction of the response for the test samples using the fitted model.

```
library(MASS)
w = ginv(t(Xtrain) %*% Xtrain) %*% t(Xtrain) %*% ytrain
pred = Xtest %*% w
```

Interestingly, the prediction has 100% accuracy when I compare with the true $ytest$. The responses are correct in all decimal points!

How come this can happen? I know this is impossible with high-dimensional data, and also, when I use `glmnet()` (with no regularization) instead of my own code, it gives 22% accuracy. So, do you have any idea about what is wrong with above code? Is there something wrong with `ginv()` (this is the first time I use it)? Does `glmnet()` function use generalized inverse as well when the sample size is smaller than the variable size?

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect with 1000 variables and 30 observations? There is nothing wrong with your code, with fewer obs than variables you can always find a perfect fit with least squares (the solution is not unique, but using `ginv` you try to get the solution with smallest norm.)

`glmnet` does **not** do this, it does not compute matrix inverses (generalized or not), it uses *regularization*, you could look through the tag [regularization](/questions/tagged/regularization).  So it does not find a least-squares solution, in stead it uses cross-validation as a help to choose the best regularization parameter (you also get a solution with regularization parameter close to zero, but this solution does not need to equal that you find with `ginv`.)

Your best bet is to go with `glmnet` and use regularization, or better, get more data.